# Parallax Scrolling moving horozontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, parallax

(Using Dreamweaver)

I am trying to create a splash advert where the graphics move as the scroller is used.
I am trying to make it so different layers move at different speeds and in different directions at the same time as the user goes further down the page.

I have managed to get it so my layers move from right to left but I can't seem to get them to move from left to right.

I have tried changing the code slightly by changing the times (*) to divide (/), removing the minus(-) and I have tried putting the images in different div sections but it doesn't seem to work.

My code is as follows.

**HTML**





 Hello world

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sky = document.getElementById("sky");
        var moon = document.getElementById("moon");
        var city = document.getElementById("city");
        var mc = document.getElementById("mc");
        var text = document.getElementById("text");
        var section1 = document.getElementById("section1");

        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
            var value = window.scrollY;
            mc.style.right = -value / 0.5 + 'px';
            sky.style.left = -value * 0.5 + 'px';
            moon.style.left =  -value * 0.5 + 'px';
            city.style.top = -value * 0.15 + 'px';
            text.style.top = value * 1 + 'px';
            section1.style.opacity = 1 -value*0.002;
    })
    </script>
```

**CSS**

```
body
    {
        background: #0a2a43;
        min-height: 1500px;
    }
    section
    {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

    }
    section:before
    {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background: linear-gradient(to top, #0a2a43 , transparent);
        z-index: 10000;
    }
    section:after
    {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #0a2a43;
        z-index: 10000;
        mix-blend-mode: color;
        opacity: .5;
    }
    section img
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        pointer-events: none;
        overflow: hidden;

    }
    section h2
    {
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 14em;
        text-shadow: 2px 4px #0a2a43;
        z-index: 1;
        cursor: none;}

    #text {
            
        position: relative;
        color: "fff";
        font-size: 10em;
        z-index: 1;
        }
        
    #mc{
       top: 700px;
       left: 10px;
       height: 300px;
       width: 100px;
       object-fit: cover;
       pointer-events: none;
       overflow: hidden;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, I just removed the (-) from the value for the "mc" and kept the style as left

```
mc.style.left = value / 0.5 + 'px';
```